# How to make a dialogflow bot perform a slack event such as renaming a channel

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, slack

I am tring to built  chatbot for slack using dialogflow. I am trying to make a chatbot which performs slack events for users such as renaming a channel and archiving a channel. When a user wants to rename a channel he can just tell this bot te channel he wants to rename and the new name of the channel and the bot performs for him. I am not able to add or code these events into my bot.

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request,response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  //const agentPath =  agent.entitiesClient.projectAgentPath("master-bot-53dee");
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) { }

  function slack_rename(agent) {
    const query = agent.query;
    let channel = agent.parameters.channel;
    let rename = agent.parameters.rename;
    let rname = agent.parameters.any;
    let a = query.split(" ");
    let i = 0;
    agent.add(`changing the name of the channel ${channel} to ${rname}`);
  }

  function slack_archive(agent){
    let channel = agent.parameters.channel;
    let archive = agent.parameters.archive;
    agent.add(`so you want to ${archive} ${channel}`);
  }

  function slack_private(agent) {
    let priv = agent.parameters.private;
    let pub = agent.parameters.public;
    let channel = agent.parameters.channel;
    agent.add(`so you want to convert ${channel} from ${pub} to ${priv}`);
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('slack-rename', slack_rename);
  intentMap.set('slack-archive', slack_archive);
  intentMap.set('slack_private', slack_private);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Have you looked into Slack's Events API? https://api.slack.com/events-api